# About connect in other server/database in Mysql

Tags: mysql

HI guys good evening .

In oracle we have dblink....
In sqlserver we have linked server

and in Mysql, what the feature to connect in other server/database ?

Comment: MySQL has only federated engine https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Comment: ok. I have the Mysql community 5.6 in AWS RDS, its possible ?

Comment: aws uses its own compilation, what they have compiled in is usually somewhere in the manual but in the faq is written that it doesn't sipport it